# C# how to convert string input from console to an enum

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert a string that i receive from the user via Console.ReadLine(); into an enum, this is the code i tried so far. I keep getting the error that im using an unassigned local variable, any advice is welcomed.

```
static Manager CreateNewManager()
    {
        Console.Write("Insert Id: ");
        int managerID = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Insert First Name: ");
        string firstName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Insert Last Name: ");
        string lastName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Insert Department");
        string department = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Select gender (M or F): ");
        string gender = Console.ReadLine();
        Gender genderEnum;
        if(gender == "M")
        {

             genderEnum = Gender.Male;
        }
        else if (gender == "F")
        {
             genderEnum = Gender.Female;
        };

        Console.Write("Insert Salary");
        int salary = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Manager newManager = new Manager(managerID, department, salary, firstName, lastName, genderEnum);
        return newManager;
```

Comment: the error is simple. There is a chance that the "genderEnum" variable could never get initialised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to elaborate on previous answers. There are three typical ways of doing this:

1) Declare an `Unknown` in your enum (as per previous answers). The downside to this is that it potentially has far-reaching implications. For example, you may only have this particular `Unknown` condition when processing input, but you may need to use your `Gender` enum all throughout your application, including lots of cases where `Unknown` is simply not a valid value. By declaring an `Unknown` member in your enum, it becomes difficult to look at a piece of code far away from this input code and determine if you need to handle the `Unknown` option.

```
enum Gender { Male, Female, Unknown }

...

Gender genderEnum;
if (gender == "M")
    genderEnum = Gender.Male;
else if (gender == "F")
    genderEnum = Gender.Female;
else
    genderEnum = Gender.Unknown;
```

2) Use a [`Nullable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx). The example below uses the [`?` syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx). The upside to this approach is that you have a cleaner enum. There may be many places in your code where this "unknown" gender isn't possible. For example, if you evaluate the input once and reject any invalid genders, then any piece of code which requires a valid gender would not need to worry about a third option. Code that needs a specific well-defined gender can use `Gender` and code that uses a potentially unknown gender can use `Gender?`.

```
enum Gender { Male, Female }

...

Gender? genderEnum;
if (gender == "M")
    genderEnum = Gender.Male;
else if (gender == "F")
    genderEnum = Gender.Female;
else
    genderEnum = null;
```

3) Throw an exception. The upside to this is that you immediately reject invalid input. Make sure you handle your exceptions appropriately.

```
enum Gender { Male, Female }

...

Gender genderEnum;
if (gender == "M")
    genderEnum = Gender.Male;
else if (gender == "F")
    genderEnum = Gender.Female;
else
    throw new ApplicationException("Invalid gender input.");
```

Comment: Thanks for the in debt answer i went with option number three, as it makes it easier for the user to understand what he did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Look at that piece of code:

```
    Gender genderEnum;
    if(gender == "M")
    {

         genderEnum = Gender.Male;
    }
    else if (gender == "F")
    {
         genderEnum = Gender.Female;
    };
```

What happens if the user enters something different than 'M' or 'F'? `genderEnum` would still not be assigned. But you try to use it anyway:

```
Manager newManager = new Manager(managerID, department, salary, firstName, lastName, genderEnum);
```

This causes the compiler error.

Initialize your genderEnum (and add that case `Unknown` to your `enum Gender`):

```
Gender genderEnum = Gender.Unknown;
```

Answer (score 1):

C# requires that all local variables are guaranteed to be assigned before they can be referenced. Because you are declaring `genderEnum` without instantiating it:

```
Gender genderEnum;
```

You need to make sure that it is assigned a value before the line where you reference it:

```
Manager newManager = new Manager(managerID, department, salary, firstName, lastName, genderEnum);
```

However, in your if-elseif chain:

```
if (gender == "M")
{
     genderEnum = Gender.Male;
}
else if (gender == "F")
{
     genderEnum = Gender.Female;
}
```

`genderEnum` could come away without a value if `gender` is neither `"M"` or `"F"`. In order for the guarantee to hold true, you either need to initialize `genderEnum` when you declare it:

```
Gender genderEnum = Gender.Unknown; // Or whatever other default value
```

or you need an else block as well:

```
else
{
    genderEnum = Gender.Unknown; // Or whatever other default value
}
```

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw Mine goes into more detail, for one thing. But regardless, I did not see the existing answer as I was busy working out my own.

Comment: Or you could also force the user to enter `M` or `F`

Comment: @MatiasCicero That alone would not help. The compiler would still see a codepath without initialization

Comment: @Psi Of course, you'd initialize the enum with a default value (be it `Male` or `Female`). It wouldn't care though, as it will be assigned later on. My point being that there would be no need for an additional `Unknown` value.

Comment: @MatiasCicero While certainly possible, it's a tad code-smell-y to initialize the value to one of the options before doing the work to determine which option to take. It's better design-wise to have a third default option so it's clear when the value hasn't been properly initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this, maybe is useful for someone.

```
public function TEnum GetConsoleEnumerator<TEnum>()  where TEnum : Enum
{
    do
    {
        Console.Write("option ---> ");
        var response = Console.ReadLine().Trim( );
        var valueIsContained = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TEnum), response);
        if (!valueIsContained)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid, try again");
            Console.ResetColor();
        }
        else
            return (TEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof( TEnum ), response, true);
    }
    while (true);
}
```